# line-height problem when using ž character

Tags: kubuntu, fonts, kate, konsole

If I write a line containgin ž in konsole or kwrite, the line height gets messed up. Is the default font broken, or is it the apps? Didn't know where to report the bug, so "ask ubuntu" sounded as a good start.

How to reproduce:

1. Open kwrite, kate or console
2. Write `__`
3. Then add a ž on the same line so you now have `__ž`

Expected behavior:

- The other chars should stay the same when I add a ž

Current behavior:

- The __ is no longer visible, guess all text get their lowest pixels removed, the _ char only have lower pixels, so easier to spot there.

In konsole, the cursor position make some differences, think it draws the text in 3 parts: before, on, and after cursor, so only the parts that include the ž char gets the error, if you wirte `__ž__` and put the cursor on the ž char, you can see the __, but if you write `__ž__ž__` you can see the 3 different parts acting.

Screenshoots as requested, first from Konsole:

[image: 4 screenshoots from konsole]

In the screenshoo i first wrote: `__ž__ž__`
and then just moving the curser between the 4 screenshoots.

Screenshoot from kwrite:
[image]

Submitted bug-report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/oxygen-fonts/+bug/1594848

Comment: Could you add screen shots how it should be and how it is?

Comment: Can at least add screenshoots on how it is now, a bit harder to screenshoot how it supose to be, as I have problem getting there :-)

Comment: OK, it is  clear now. Could you tell me which Kubuntu is this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce same  issue on Kubuntu 15.10 (VBox). It is a font problem. It happen with "Oxygen Mono", it doesn't with "Ubuntu Mono" & "Deja Vu Mono".

1. Find the corresponding font file

   ```
   $ fc-match "Oxygen Mono"
   OxygenMono-Regular.ttf: "Oxygen Mono" "Regular"
   ```
2. Find the source package and the full path

   ```
   $ dpkg -S OxygenMono-Regular.ttf
   fonts-oxygen: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/oxygen/OxygenMono-Regular.ttf
   ```
3. Collect info

   ```
   ubuntu-bug /usr/share/fonts/truetype/oxygen/OxygenMono-Regular.ttf
   ```

   Then send (It will open a link in the browser)
4. Complete Lauchpad bug report and submit

If things get slow, You may submit another report to upstream project [KDE](https://www.kde.org/). Just update both reports to include the links to each others.

Here a command to show package info including the upstream link...

```
$ apt-cache show fonts-oxygen
Package: fonts-oxygen
...
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian/Kubuntu Qt/KDE Maintainers <debian-qt-kde@lists.debian.org>
...
Source: oxygen-fonts
Version: 4:5.4.3-0ubuntu1
...
Homepage: https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/workspace/oxygen-fonts
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 3y
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, have reported it at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/oxygen-fonts/+bug/1594848
(should i mark this as solved in askubuntu now, or after it is fixed?)

Comment: @PugganSe, mark it accepted here, as  It does answer your question "Is the default font broken, or is it the apps? Didn't know where to report the bug" , and because Ask Ubuntu is not for tracking bugs. Just don 't forget to add an update note down the question mentioning the submitted but report. I will help others facing same issue.